# I can not find sum of the prefix number using stack

Tags: c++, stack, prefix

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class StackNode
{
public:
    StackNode *  topPtr = NULL;
    StackNode* next;
    string item;
bool push( string newItem) {

   // create a new node
   StackNode *newPtr = new StackNode;

   // set data portion  of new node
   newPtr->item = newItem;

   // insert the new node
   newPtr->next = topPtr;
   topPtr = newPtr;

   return true;
}
bool pop() {

   if (topPtr == NULL)
      return false;

   // stack is not empty; delete top
   else{
      StackNode *temp = topPtr;
      topPtr = topPtr->next;

      // return deleted node to system
      temp->next = NULL;  // safeguard
      delete temp;
      return true;
   }
}
int ope(string op, string val1,string val2)
{

    int vaL1 = stoi(val1);
    int vaL2 = stoi(val2);

    int res = 0;
    if( op == "*")
        res = vaL1 * vaL2;
if( op == "/")
        res = vaL1 / vaL2;
if( op == "-")
        res = vaL1 - vaL2;
if( op == "+")
        res = vaL1 + vaL2;
return res;
}
int cal(string pre_exp[],int len)
{
    int numb = 0;

    for(int i = len -1;i>=0;i--)
    {

       if ( pre_exp[i] == "*" || pre_exp[i] == "/" || pre_exp[i] == "+" || pre_exp[i] == "-")
        {

       string op1 = topPtr->item;
       pop();
       string op2 = topPtr->item;
       pop();

      numb = numb + ope(pre_exp[i],op1,op2);
    }
    else
    {
       push( (pre_exp[i]));
    }
}
  return numb;
}
int main()
{
StackNode nbr;
string eyoo[] = {"+","-","2","3","9"};
cout<< nbr.cal(eyoo,5)<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Hello everyone, I am trying find the sum of a prefix expression. My code is here. Weirdly, I don't get any output. The method cal does not return the number, probably the program gets stucks in the for loop of the method calc. Can someone help me please? Pop and push methods work, I tested them with a display method. The problem must be in the usage of stoi or in the calc method as I said.

Comment: This seems like a very good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I tried. Is asking for  debug help is wrong on this website?

Comment: The key to debugging is learning how to execute your code/algorithm 1 line at a time looking at your variables at each step. Don't just run your code in the debugger and think it will tell you what is wrong. Most of the time it won't.

Comment: I have printed nearly every line, but deleted those while uploading the code to keep the code more easy to understand.I know how to debug but I couldn't debug this one. Believe me, I am not doing this first time. Anyone knows what is the problem?

Comment: Sounds like you need an IDE with a good debugger like Visual Studio or perhaps one with gdb.

Comment: @BenBitdiddle it is easy to understand the problem, no need of a debugger even to use a debugger or _valgrind_ is **very** useful. Please look at my answer

Comment: @BenBitdiddle *I know how to debug but I couldn't debug this one* -- Every  line of code you write,  you must know what all the lines of code you are writing is supposed to produce.  When your program finally runs, but doesn't produce the output, there is no excuse as to not knowing how to debug the code.  You had a plan when you wrote the code -- when the code does not follow the plan, i.e. a variable is not set correctly, the logic flows different than your plan, then you debug to see where the program goes counter to your logic.  Otherwise you're just writing "stuff" and hoping it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   string op1 = topPtr->item;
   pop();
   string op2 = topPtr->item;
   pop();
```

you always pop the 2 operands of an operator, that supposes you push the result, but you do not do, at a given time *topPtr* become null, with your example this is when you do `string op2 = topPtr->item;`

for me `numb = numb + ope(pre_exp[i],op1,op2);` must be replaced by pushing the result of `ope(pre_exp[i],op1,op2)` in the stack at the place of the two poped values

so for `{"+","-","2","3","9"}` :

- push 9
- push 3
- push 2
- `-` so *pop=2 - pop=3* = -1, and you have to push -1
- `+` so *pop=-1 + pop=9* = 8 and you push 8  (without the push -1 before the stack is empty when getting the second operand)
- all is done so you pop the result = 8

---

However I am surprised you star by the end of the expression, I am not sure that works in all the case an compute well the result, why you do not start by the beginning ?

---

A final remark : all your method try to be inline (defined in the class), we use inline when a method is small, better to move the definitions out of the class for your methods